# VectorOfPoint (EmguCV) object intermittently loses its internal point list. GC?

Tags: c#, .net, emgucv

I have some image processing software that is written in C# .NET and uses the EmguCV library, which is a wrapper around OpenCV. I have a really weird intermittent bug.

In the code there are three lines like this:

```
Mat diff = BackgroundModel.Difference(mat, CurrentReceptacle);
var (crops, contours) = Segmenter.Segment(mat, diff, (int)ProcessingIntensityThreshold, ProcessingPixelAreaThreshold, 1.1);
BackgroundModel.Update(mat, contours, CurrentReceptacle);
```

`contours` is a `List<VectorOfPoint>`, where `VectorOfPoint` is an EmguCV class that contains a list of points that can be obtained as `System.Drawing.Point`, but I think they are actually some kind of generic object in the underlying OpenCV unmanaged code.

Randomly I get an exception in `BackgroundModel.Update` which (indirectly) indicates that one of the `VectorOfPoint` objects in `contours` has size 0. The debugger confirms this. Always it is when `contours` list has just one `VectorOfPoint` object.

However, this is weird behaviour, as `Segmenter.Segment` only returns `VectorOfPoint` objects in `contours` if they are above a certain size. So I sprinkled a few `Console.WriteLine(contours[0].Size)` in the code, and discovered that even though I got an exception indicating the `VectorOfPoint` has size zero, and the debugger confirms this, at the time of writing to the console, the `VectorOfPoint`object actually contains say 300 `Point`.

So somewhere between `Segmenter.Segment` and `BackgroundModel.Update`, `contours[0]` is losing all the `Point`s it contains...

The problem happens randomly, maybe every 2000 or 3000 calls. Usually the contour that 'disappears' is quite small, maybe 300 points instead of 1000 or more. Furthermore, running the code again with the same inputs does NOT repeat the problem.

What could possibly be going on here? My first thought is something is getting garbage collected? Or perhaps something weird where the underlying unmanaged object is cleared?

Questions:

- What kind of troubleshooting steps can I try to explore the problem further?
- Is it possible that the garbage collector is involved?
- Should I avoid returning things in a tuple?
- Any solutions?

Here is the code for the `Segment` method. (Note that there is another `VectorOfPoint` called `shiftedContour` that is a copy of `contours[i]`, I have never noticed that this contour is 'cleared')

```
public static (List<MaskedMat>, List<VectorOfPoint>) Segment(Mat mat, Mat diff, int threshold, int areaThreshold, double buffer)
{
    //Greyscale
    VectorOfVectorOfPoint contours = FindBinaryContours(diff, threshold);

    //Get the bigger contours
    List<VectorOfPoint> largeContours = new List<VectorOfPoint>();
    for (int i = 0; i < contours.Size; i++)
    {
        double area = CvInvoke.ContourArea(contours[i]);
        if (area > areaThreshold) largeContours.Add(contours[i]);
    }

    //Crop the images
    List<MaskedMat> crops = new List<MaskedMat>();
    foreach (VectorOfPoint contour in largeContours)
    {
        //Centroid
        MCvMoments moments = CvInvoke.Moments(contour);
        //Centroid(moments);
        var centreX = (int) Math.Round(moments.M10 / moments.M00);
        var centreY = (int) Math.Round(moments.M01 / moments.M00);
        Point centroid = new Point(centreX, centreY);

        //Get max radius
        double maxRadius = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < contour.Size; i++)
        {
            double radius = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(contour[i].X - centreX, 2) + Math.Pow(contour[i].Y - centreY, 2));
            if (radius > maxRadius)
            {
                maxRadius = radius;
            }
        }

        //Crop area
        int halfWidth = (int) Math.Round(maxRadius * buffer);
        SquareWithinBounds sq = new SquareWithinBounds(centroid, halfWidth, mat.Size);

        //Crop
        var cropArea = sq.Rectangle;
        Mat cropTemp = new Mat(mat, cropArea);
        Mat crop = new Mat();
        cropTemp.CopyTo(crop);
        cropTemp.Dispose();

        //Raw mask
        Mat mask = new Mat(mat.Rows, mat.Cols, DepthType.Cv8U, 1);
        mask.SetTo(new MCvScalar(0));
        VectorOfVectorOfPoint contourArray = new VectorOfVectorOfPoint(contour.Clone());
        CvInvoke.FillPoly(mask, contourArray, new MCvScalar(255));
        Mat maskTemp = new Mat(mask, cropArea);
        mask = new Mat();
        maskTemp.CopyTo(mask);
        maskTemp.Dispose();

        //Shift contour
        var shiftedContour = contour.Translate((Size)Point.Subtract(sq.Centroid, (Size)centroid));
        crops.Add(new MaskedMat(crop, mask, shiftedContour, sq.Centroid));
    }                  
    return (crops, largeContours);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved this

The problem was in here:

```
//Greyscale (contours is VectorOfVectorOfPoint)
var contours = FindBinaryContours(diff, threshold);

//Get the bigger contours
List<VectorOfPoint> largeContours = new List<VectorOfPoint>();
for (int i = 0; i < contours.Size; i++)
{
    double area = CvInvoke.ContourArea(contours[i]);
    if (area > areaThreshold) largeContours.Add(contours[i]);
}
```

Specifically `largeContours.Add(contours[i]);` had to be changed to `largeContours.Add(contours[i].Clone());` where `Clone` is an extension method I created:

```
public static VectorOfPoint Clone(this VectorOfPoint contour)
{
    List<Point> cloned = new List<Point>(contour.Size);
    for (int i = 0; i < contour.Size; i++)
    {
        Point p = new Point(contour[i].X, contour[i].Y);
        cloned.Add(p);
    }
    return new VectorOfPoint(cloned.ToArray());
}
```